# Can Repeater delegate in Qml be made to behave in a generic way to the given Items?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

{New to Qml (quick 2.0 using Qt 5.1 beta) and learning}.

I wanted to know if such an idiom would be possible in Qml:
Below I have objLeftColumn which expects its children to expose a boolean m_bIsSelected and a MouseArea alias m_mouseProperty and uses them to make the collection of such children mutually exclusive, ie., only one of them can be in selected state. The followin works fine but I need to repeat it every time I want and specially if I wanted it for Row etc.

```
Column {
        id: objLeftColumn

        property int m_iLastButtonClicked: -1
        property int m_iCurrentButtonClicked: -1

        onM_iCurrentButtonClickedChanged: {
            if(m_iLastButtonClicked != -1) {
                objLeftColumn.children[m_iLastButtonClicked].m_bIsSelected = false
            }
            m_iLastButtonClicked = m_iCurrentButtonClicked
        }

        Repeater {
            id: objLeftColumnRepeater

            model: 5

            delegate: ABCD {
                id: objABCD

                m_mouseProperty.onClicked: {
                    if(m_bIsSelected) {
                        objLeftColumn.m_iCurrentButtonClicked = index
                    }
                    else {
                        objLeftColumn.m_iLastButtonClicked = -1
                        objLeftColumn.m_iCurrentButtonClicked = -1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Can I write a generic objLeftColumn (in a separate qml file) that could arrange the given Items in Column while aslo dealing with exclusivity of their selection?

The idea is instead of giving the component to the delegate right there an then, I'll give it later and for each instantiation of the component (depending on numeric value of model above and below) the delegate: in Repeater should behave similarly.

eg., in psedo code:

in Exclusive.qml:

```
Column {
        id: objLeftColumn

        property int m_iLastButtonClicked: -1
        property int m_iCurrentButtonClicked: -1
        property alias m_delegate: objLeftColumnRepeater.delegate

        onM_iCurrentButtonClickedChanged: {
            if(m_iLastButtonClicked != -1) {
                objLeftColumn.children[m_iLastButtonClicked].m_bIsSelected = false
            }
            m_iLastButtonClicked = m_iCurrentButtonClicked
        }

        Repeater {
            id: objLeftColumnRepeater

            model: 5

           onItemAdded: {
               //state of item can be manipulated but want to
               //add behaviour to the item eg:
            /*item {
                 m_mouseProperty.onClicked: {
                 //do something
                 }
           }*/
           }
        }
}
```

in SomeOther.qml:

```
Exclusive {
    model: 5
    delegate: ABCD
}

Exclusive {
    model: 9
    delegate: DEFG
}
```

etc..So this way Column in Exclusive is more generic and can be called with any Item assigned to its delegate and will behave similarly. Is this possible in qml

Answer (score 1):

This needs a bit of trickery to be solved, I can think of two ways:

1. Use the JS [connect()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmlevents.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals) function to manually create the connections. Something like this:

   ```
   Repeater {
       id: objLeftColumnRepeater
       model: 5

       onItemAdded: {
           item.m_mouseProperty.onClicked.connect(function() {
               console.log("Clicked!");
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. Wrap the delegate into an `Item` by using a `Loader`, and use a[`Connections`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-qtquick2-connections.html) element for the connection. Something like this:

   ```
   property Component delegate
   Repeater {
       id: objLeftColumnRepeater
       model: 5
       delegate: Item {
           Loader {
               id: loader
               sourceComponent: delegate
           }

           Connections {
               target: loader.item.m_mouseProperty
               onClicked: console.log("Clicked")                
           }
       }
   ```